# Separate appdomain for a referenced dll in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, dll, reference, appdomain, lifecycle

Can we have a separate appdomain for a referenced dll in dotnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The referenced assembly will be loaded along with the main assembly in the same AppDomain. If you want to load an assembly into a separate AppDomain, then you need to explicitly create this AppDomain and load the assembly into it. The assembly should not be added as reference in this case to the main project.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.